# PCB electrical connection with a M5 screw

Tags: surface-mount

What would be your recommendation for a PCB electrical connection with a M5 screw passing vertically through a hole on the PCB? It cannot be a thread connection since the screw is axially fixed (the screw is prevented to displace axially and can only rotate) and it would push the PCB when it is rotated after assembly. The electrical connection doesn't require to work while the screw is rotated. It should also allow it rotate indefinitely. The maximum current is 3.3A.

[image]

I have been looking for a leaf spring, maybe a closed U shape mounted vertically on the PCB so the screw pass through it and makes contact with both extremities.

I am also considering to use a wave spring (see picture) between the lock washer and a circular pad around the hole on the PCB.

[image: wave spring]

Comment: You mentioned in another comment that the screw is going to rotate after assembly. That's a pretty important detail. I don't know what "axially fixed" means—does that mean that the screw is prevented from moving in any manner besides rotating about its own axis? Does the screw rotate clockwise, counterclockwise, or both, as seen from the side of the board on which you want to make the connection? How good a connection do you need—is it okay if, while the screw is rotating, the connection is intermittent?

Comment: I think you need a cable in there someplace.

Comment: Yes, your understanding of axially fixed is right. The screw is perpendicular to the board, pass through a hole and will rotate in both ways. An intermittent connection while the screw is rotating is not a problem. Tks.

Comment: For 10 Amp, I would definitely want a wire solidly attached to the PCB and to wherever else it connects.  I don't think any sort of sliding contact would be reliable.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the maximum current. It is 3.3A not 10A as I wrote before. The screw is rotated so I do need a sliding contact.

Comment: What angle will the screw rotate? 360°, 1080°, or ....?

Comment: The screw should be able to rotate indefinitely.

Comment: What you need goes by the name "rotary joint".  Reliable ones are a bit more complicated than what OP is proposing.

Comment: Thanks, a rotary joint would do the job, but I am looking for a cost effective solution. Also rotary joints are designed usually for several channels. What about a leaf spring or wave spring as I explained in my question? Batteries are connected by springs and the difference here is that the wave spring would be sliding over the golden ring pad on the PCB, or a leaf spring would be sliding over the screw, in a very same way that rotary joints work.

Comment: Spring steel is not as conductive as you might think.  You might find this gets REALLY hot.  You better test the heck out of whatever you come up with.  Its very embarrassing when your products catch fire.    Also -  Gold is a terrible choice for anything that has to move or slide --- Too soft.   I would look for brass or beryllium copper hardware.

Comment: What distance will the PCB be moving? Could you attach one end of a wire to the case, coil it round a couple of times (or more, like a coiled phone cable), and attach the other end to the PCB? It's often better to keep electrical and mechanical functions separate if you can.

Comment: @Kyle, thanks, those are all important points to consider. Yes, everything will be tested. About the heat and conductivity we can dimension it accordingly as we do with a wire, I don't see the issue here, as I mentioned before batteries are well connected by springs and that's what we would like to reproduce here. About the material the screw will not be rotated continuously so shouldn't be a big concern, anyway we would  look for a suitable material.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks a lot for your suggestion. The screw should be able to rotate indefinitely so a coiled wire could not be used. The screw pass perpendicularly  through the board.

Comment: @pedroalbaladejo I meant that the screw should be one thing, and the wire be a completely separate thing that does not rotate (assuming the PCB does not rotate relative to the case), if I wasn't clear in my previous comment.

Comment: @pedroalbaladejo   I should be a little clearer with the heat thing....  It's not "contact resistance" I'm talking about  (not the metal-to-metal connection).   The MATERIAL is a resistor.... Much more resistive than most steels.  I don't know why, maybe a metallurgist can explain, but "spring steel" has a high electrical resistance.   What can happen is a runaway thermal effect.  The metal gets a bit warm, so its resistance goes up.  But the resistance is now higher, so it creates more heat, and it gets hotter.  Then the resistance goes up again, etc... until your spring is glowing red.

Comment: I would test this at some current level far above your expected use.  Like >10A at least.   Maybe more.

Answer (score 2):

With a slight tweak to the question, it won't run fowl of the local rules about design work: **How would you connect PCB's together to carry higher current?**

What you are after is either the Redcube series from Wurth (https://www.we-online.com/web/en/electronic_components/produkte_pb/produktinnovationen/redcube.php) or the PowerElement (or PowerTap) series from ERNI (https://www.erni.com/en/products-and-solutions/electronic-connectors/power-elements)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The issue I have is that the screw will be rotating after assembly, since it is a movable part of the system, and it is fixed axially respect to the PCB so if I use a thread connection it will be pushing the PCB. The redcube with the spring loaded connection looks good but it is for horizontal connections, while I have a M5 stud passing through a hole on the board.